# Erro na configuração do Sdk do Android no Linux

Tags: android, linux, react-native, android-sdk

**O sistema operacional é Linux Mint**

**Ao inserir:**

```
~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-27" "build-tools;27.0.3"
acontece o seguinte erro:
```

**Tô quebrando a cabeça aqui...**

```
Warning: Could not create settings
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.<init>(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:428)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:152)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:134)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:57)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Usage:
  sdkmanager [--uninstall] [<common args>] [--package_file=<file>] [<packages>...]
  sdkmanager --update [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --list [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --licenses [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --version

With --install (optional), installs or updates packages.
    By default, the listed packages are installed or (if already installed)
    updated to the latest version.
With --uninstall, uninstall the listed packages.

    <package> is a sdk-style path (e.g. "build-tools;23.0.0" or
             "platforms;android-23").
    <package-file> is a text file where each line is a sdk-style path
                   of a package to install or uninstall.
    Multiple --package_file arguments may be specified in combination
    with explicit paths.

With --update, all installed packages are updated to the latest version.

With --list, all installed and available packages are printed out.

With --licenses, show and offer the option to accept licenses for all
     available packages that have not already been accepted.

With --version, prints the current version of sdkmanager.

Common Arguments:
    --sdk_root=<sdkRootPath>: Use the specified SDK root instead of the SDK
                              containing this tool

    --channel=<channelId>: Include packages in channels up to <channelId>.
                           Common channels are:
                           0 (Stable), 1 (Beta), 2 (Dev), and 3 (Canary).

    --include_obsolete: With --list, show obsolete packages in the
                        package listing. With --update, update obsolete
                        packages as well as non-obsolete.

    --no_https: Force all connections to use http rather than https.

    --proxy=<http | socks>: Connect via a proxy of the given type.

    --proxy_host=<IP or DNS address>: IP or DNS address of the proxy to use.

    --proxy_port=<port #>: Proxy port to connect to.

    --verbose: Enable verbose output.

* If the env var REPO_OS_OVERRIDE is set to "windows",
  "macosx", or "linux", packages will be downloaded for that OS.
```

Comment: JDK está instalada?

Comment: Está sim meu camarada. Será que se baixar toda ferramenta do Android Studio adianta?

Comment: É, talvez funcione. Eu estava sofrendo com esse mesmo problema hoje. Em alguns posts eu vi que isso poderia ser um problema com a verão da SDK Tools. Que foi o que esse cara disse nesse post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60443891/sdkmanager-command-line-execution-error-linux

Comment: Daí eu fiz o downgrade. Peguei os links nesse post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049883/android-sdk-tools-older-version-with-working-android-tool

Consegui instalar os packages de boa.

Comment: Agora estou tentando buildar aqui. Por enquanto tá dando certo.

Comment: É deu certo viu. Tenta aí pra ver.

Comment: Opa, agora foi meu camarada. Show de bola amigo. Te agradeço por essa moral. Forte abraço...

Comment: Que bom que deu certo.

Comment: Aparentemente isso é um erro com o propio SDK tools, faça downgrade da versão e verifique se funciona http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-macosx.zip - MacOS X http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip - Windows http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-linux.zip - Linux

Comment: **Espero poder ajudar os demais com a ótima experiência.** **O camarada, que por comentário privado, me forneceu ajuda com êxito pelo seguinte link:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049883/android-sdk-tools-older-version-with-working-android-tool

Answer (score 1):

Luka, tentei executar os comandos a seguir.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Depois que concluir verifique se o Java está instalado na sua máquina.

```
java -version
```

Caso tenha outras versões do Java instaladas na máquina, precisa colocar a 8 como padrão:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Pra emular, talvez precise das libs de 32bits

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib lib32z1 lib32stdc++6
```

Conteúdo retirado do material da Rocketseat. 
https://docs.rocketseat.dev/ambiente-react-native/android/linux

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Opa, fala Rafael, beleza? Então meu camarada, foi com base nessa documentação que me guio e me guiei nesse caso, mas ao tentar fazer em notebook me deu esse erro. Já no desktop fluiu normalmente.

Comment: Então faz os seguintes passos.

Vá até sua pasta
`~/Android/Sdk/tools/bins/`
E execute
`./sdkmanager --sdk_root=${pwd} --licenses`
Depois teste de novo, caso não dê certo, rode o comando como sudo

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a documentação deveria estar correto, porém tive o mesmo problema. Resolvi da seguinte forma:

Mova a pasta "tools" para dentro de uma pasta chamada "cmdline-tools". Seu comando ficaria assim:

```
/Android/Sdk/cmdline-tools/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-27" "build-tools;27.0.3"
```

O comando acima deve funcionar sem nenhum erro, mas estou supondo que suas variáveis de ambiente estão configuradas como algo assim:

```
export JAVA_HOME=CAMINHO_ANOTADO_COM_SUA_VERSÃO
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Se quiser uma resposta mais detalhada, veja a discussão [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440509/android-command-line-tools-sdkmanager-always-shows-warning-could-not-create-se) (em inglês)